# Create TypeSafe Object literal based upon existing object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

Consider the following function:

```
function keysToValuesClone<TObject extends {}>(keysAndValuesObj: TObject) {
    const clone = Object.assign({}, keysAndValuesObj);

    Object.keys(clone).forEach(key => clone[key] = key);

    const frozen = Object.freeze(clone);

    return (<any>frozen) as Readonly<{ // The `any` is regrettable... see below
        [K in keyof typeof clone]: K
    }>;
}
```

I can supply this function with an object literal like so:

```
const myHeaders = keysToValuesClone({
    'a property with spaces': '',
    'and another': '',
});
```

And the produced `myHeaders` will have this type:

```
Readonly<{
    'a property with spaces': "a property with spaces";
    'and another': "and another";
}>
```

I like the utility of this function but writing it has raised 2 questions in my mind:

### Is it possible to lose the `any`?

If I change the final line of `keysToValuesClone` to this:

```
    return frozen as Readonly<{
        [K in keyof typeof clone]: K
    }>;
```

Then I'm landed with the following error:

```
Type 'Readonly<TObject & {}>' cannot be converted to type 'Readonly<{ [K in keyof (TObject & {})]: K; }>'.
  Type '(TObject & {})[P]' is not comparable to type 'P'.
```

I've tried convincing the compiler in many different ways to allow this function without the `any` type assertion but all attempts fail.  Is this improvable?  Can you convince the compiler to come along for the ride without resorting to `any`?

### Is it possible to create a similar function that constructs this type from a `string[]`?

I'd quite like to write this code:

```
const myHeaders = keysToValuesUsingArray([
    'a property with spaces',
    'and another'
]);
```

i.e. supply a string array and have it output the same as the above.  Codewise I can achieve this like so:

```
function keysToValuesArray(keys: string[]) {
    const obj = keys.reduce((objInTheMaking, key) => ({ [key]: key, ...objInTheMaking  }), {});

    return obj;
}
```

But this produces the type `{}`.  Is there a way to clue in the type system to what is happening here?

I've played with `keyof / typeof / Tuple` etc all to no avail.  And so my friends I turn to you.

Educate me.

---

### Thanks Titian!

That's awesome Titian; thanks so much!  I ended up rolling with your array solution with Readonly tweaks; see below: (I've unaccountably got a lot of love for `Object.freeze` right now; it's my jam)

```
function keysToValuesArray<T extends string>(keys: T[]): Readonly<{ [P in T] : P}> {
    const obj = keys.reduce((objInTheMaking, key) => ({ [key]: key, ...objInTheMaking  }), {} );

    const frozen = Object.freeze(obj);

    return frozen as Readonly<{ [P in T] : P}>;
}
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can create an object from a `string` array, if we use a generic type parameter to represent the fields names:

```
function keysToValuesArray<T extends string>(keys: T[]) : { [P in T] : P}{
    const obj = keys.reduce((objInTheMaking, key) => ({ [key]: key, ...objInTheMaking  }), {} );
    return obj as { [P in T] : P};
}
const myHeaders2 = keysToValuesArray([
    'a property with spaces',
    'and another'
]);
```

As o avoiding a cast to `any`, you can type `clone` directly as `any` or `{ [n: string]: any }` but that will not be much better. While building these objects they don't conform to the type anyway, so it doesn't make much difference.  I usually take solace in the idea that the call site is type safe which is more important.

```
function keysToValuesClone<TObject extends {}>(keysAndValuesObj: TObject) {
    const clone : { [n: string]: any } = Object.assign({}, keysAndValuesObj);

    Object.keys(clone).forEach(key => clone[key] = key);

    const frozen = Object.freeze(clone);

    return frozen as Readonly<{ 
        [K in keyof typeof clone]: K
    }>;
}
```