# Return exact generic type from function

Tags: typescript, types, literals

Consider following scenario:
I have a function `createObj` which take one parameter(which is object) with type of `ExampleType`, and then it creates new object with property `def` which contains provided object. I want it to return also type, which contain the exact same type as provided. Look at example below:

```
type ExampleType = { aaa: string };
declare type MyFunc = <T>(obj?: ExampleType) => { def: O };
const myFunc: MyFunc;

const a = myFunc({aaa: 'name'});
```

For now it returns `{ def: any }`, but I want it to return exact value which is provided - `{ def: { aaa: 'name' } }`. Is there any chance to do that? Or even simplier, take a look on this:

```js
const aObj = { a: true };

type aType = { a: true };
```

Is there any way to get type from `aObj` to be equal `aType`?

EDIT: 
Ok, I found partial answer for my question (based on this: [Create TypeSafe Object literal based upon existing object in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176206/create-typesafe-object-literal-based-upon-existing-object-in-typescript)).

```js
function myFunc<O>(keysAndValuesObj: O) {
  return { def: keysAndValuesObj } as {
    def: { [K in keyof typeof keysAndValuesObj]: K };
  };
}
const a = myFunc({
  aaa: 'abc'
});
// now variable a is type of { def: { aaa: 'abc' } }
```

all I need now is to make `myFunc` argument to be type of `ExampleType`. I was trying extending `O` with `ExampleType` type, but without success...

Comment: Your question is vague and contains many elements not shown in code. For your final snippet, have you tried `type aType = typeof aObj;`?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic, yes, but it returns ```{ a: boolean }```, and I want it to return ```{ a: true }```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correct, you have a function which takes an object as a parameter. You want to return an object with the shape of `{ def: objectParemeter }` but you want the type of the object passed in to be preserved in the output.

If that's the case something like this will work:

```
const createObj = <ObjType extends object>(obj: ObjType) => ({ def: obj })
```

If you want the return type to exactly match some type you can do:

```
const example2 = createObj<ExampleType>({ aaa: 'name' })
```

Which has type `{ def: ExampleType }`

You can play around with this example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ExampleType%20%3D%20%7B%20aaa%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20createObj%20%3D%20%3CObjType%20extends%20object%3E(obj%3A%20ObjType)%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%20def%3A%20obj%20%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test1%20%3D%20createObj(%7B%20aaa%3A%20'name'%20%7D)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20test2%20%3D%20createObj%3CExampleType%3E(%7B%20aaa%3A%20'name'%20%7D)%0D%0Aconst%20test3%3A%20%7B%20def%3A%20ExampleType%20%7D%20%3D%20createObj(%7B%20aaa%3A%20'name'%20%7D)%0D%0A)

Comment: Thanks, it works fine, except it doesn't return exact type (for strings it's called 'string literal'). I updated my question, as I found partially solution for my problem. Have a look, maybe now you will be able to help me.

Comment: Typescript won't match a shape of an object literal to another custom type that happens to be the same thing. You'll need to use that type in a type assertion or a generic. I have examples of this in the linked playground. Updated answer, including your new code which give you the desired type `{ def: ExampleType }`